# Batch insert slow with SQLAlchemy core?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I got batch insert working with SQLAlchemy and Postgres, but I assumed it would speed things up significantly... I'm trying to insert 24k rows where one column is provided and the others are null (five columns total). I've changed the batch amount from 1,000 to 10,000, and it's still taking ages, around five minutes.

Am I doing something wrong? It's a Postgres server running on my local network, and shouldn't have an issue.

Relevant Code below, and please note that 'insert' is from the postgres specialized library, imported at the top.

```
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import insert

def insert_domains_batch(self,domains):

    threshold = 10000

    while domains:
        batch = []
        while len(batch) <= threshold and domains:
            batch.append({"url": domains.pop()})
        stmt = insert(self.domains)
        stmt = stmt.on_conflict_do_nothing()
        self.connection.execute(stmt, batch)
```

Comment: If you are using psycopg2 as the driver and have not passed any of the [fast execution helper flags](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/postgresql.html#psycopg2-fast-execution-helpers) when creating the engine, you are still inserting one by one due to how the driver handles `executemany`. For really large batches consider creating a temporary table, using COPY to move the data, and inserting with conflict resolution from the temporary.